# Python, reverse some lines down to up

Tags: python-2.7

I don't know how to do this:

```
a b c d e 1
a b c d e 2
a b c d e 3
...
a b c d e n
```

and need:

```
a b c d e n
....
a b c d e 3
a b c d e 2
a b c d e 1
```

I tried something like:

```
newcontent=codecs.encode(content,'utf_8','replace')
for i in reversed(newcontent):
    newcontent.append(i)
    print newcontent
```

Comment: What output do you get when running your code?

Comment: put everything in a list then do: `my_list[::-1]` or iterate over `reversed(my_list)`.